# What is this icon on top right corner of screen?

Tags: notification-icons

I have an android phone which shows a peculiar icon on top right corner of the screen (notification area):

[image]

I believe:

```
Icon number 1 is for signal
Icon number 3 is for wifi
Icon number 4 is for battery.
```

What does icon number 2 indicate? I could not find it on searching the net. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. I agree it looks very similar. I hope this does not pose any security risk.

Comment: Of course not, it's a facility by network provider. Disable it if you don't want it (ask your provider if you can't find it in your settings)